# Extra padding at bottom of HTML linked image in Chrome, IE6, and Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I am having a problem with a linked image.

```
<TR class="a"> 
    <TD><A href="http://CA_NB_1_1-pr.jpg" rel="lightbox"><IMG src="CA_NB_1_1-th-pr.jpg"><BR><BR></A></TD> 
    <TD class="hdsmlbr"><A href="http://127.0.0.1/odds/aptrqr2/view/1">35 Savoie Drive, Moncton, New Brunswick, Canada</A></TD>
</TR>
```

This image has padding at the bottom of it that I cannot seem to find to kill. I have used CSS Reset from Yahoo to see if that helped, and even removed all CSS to see if I can locate the problem.

Using Firebug, I tried a few on the fly methods of nullifying the padding, but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone else figure out what the problem may be?

http://monkeylook.bendauphinee.com/

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Sometimes it really is the stupidly simple things that you miss :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be the two `<br>`'s...

Answer (score 1):

You're trailing your image with two break-tags: `<BR><BR>`. Those would give the same impression. Sure enough, when removed the "extra padding" vanishes.

Answer (score 1):

you have two newlines in your a tag?
try this.

```
<TR class="a"> 
    <TD><A href="http://CA_NB_1_1-pr.jpg" rel="lightbox"><IMG src="CA_NB_1_1-th-pr.jpg"></A></TD> 
    <TD class="hdsmlbr"><A href="http://127.0.0.1/odds/aptrqr2/view/1">35 Savoie Drive, Moncton, New Brunswick, Canada</A></TD>
</TR>
```